# Horizontal scrollable div with flexgrow on main container

Tags: css, sass, flexbox, material-ui

I am using Material UI, on the container it has the property `flexgrow:1`

I am trying to have a scrollable horizontal div that contains cards, it is actually simple if the approach didn't had flexgrow.

For simple scrollable i could've used [this](https://codeburst.io/how-to-create-horizontal-scrolling-containers-d8069651e9c6), but because of the flex properties that i don't truly understand yet, i am banging my head to the wall now. (note: if you have a great reference to allow me understand how it fully works, i would greatly appreciate it).

## CSS:

```
.scrolling-wrapper {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;

  .card {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    width: 320px;
    height: 180px;
    margin: 15px;
    padding: 15px;
  }
}
```

## HTML:

```
<div className="scrolling-wrapper">
    <Card className="card">Test</Card>
    <Card className="card">Test</Card>
    <Card className="card">Test</Card>
    <Card className="card">Test</Card>
    <Card className="card">Test</Card>
    <Card className="card">Test</Card>
</div>
```

For simplicity i minimized everything.

What happens is, when i set `width: 100% or 100vw` it exceeds the screen. `100%` doesn't fill the parent width and the `100vw` adds the width of my sidebar instead of `vw` itself. Meaning, instead the scrollbar will happen to be at the `scrolling-wrapper` it is being attached to the most base container.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
.scrolling-wrapper .card { 
  ...
  flex: 1;
  width: 320px;
  ...
}
```

with:

```
.scrolling-wrapper .card {
  ...
  flex: 0 0 320px; 
  ...
}
```

See it [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-playground-5ww4o).

---

**Explanation**: `flex: 1; width: 320px;`, in your case, translates to:

```
flex-grow: 1;    /* I grow if there's available space      */
flex-shrink: 1;  /* I shrink if there's not enough space   */
flex-basis: 0%;  /* initial flex-basis (width): 0%         */
width: 320px;    /* ignored (overwritten by `flex-basis`)  */
```

You don't want your card to grow if there's additional space:

```
flex-grow: 0;
```

You don't want your card to shrink if there's not enough space:

```
flex-shrink: 0;
```

You want your card to start from (and remain at) a width of `320px`

```
flex-basis: 320px;
```

You don't need `width`.
Also, in case you have any case where cards don't fill the width of the container, you probably want to set

```
.scrolling-wrapper {
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

(instead of `scroll`), so you don't render a useless scrollbar.

---

And now, that I answered your question, I need to ask one myself: why are you displaying the cards with flexbox? Because the flexbox inside the `.scrolling-wrapper` has ***nothing*** to do with the flexbox it is part of.

The only reason to display the cards using flexbox would be if you wanted them spread when there aren't enough cards to fill the width of the container, with `justify-content: space-between;`, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

As you can see, it can be done with flexbox, but it can very well be done with `display: block; white-space: nowrap;`, as in the article you linked, *while* `.scrolling-wrapper` has `flex-grow: 1`, so it expands over the entire available space (assuming the other children have `flex-grow: 0`). Currently, you're giving no info on what's going on outside `.scrolling-wrapper` and I believe that's what you're having trouble with.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for a very detailed and clear explanation for my basic trouble. on the parent of `.scrolling-wrapper` it has a `flex-grow: 1`. does the first integer in the `flex` property means for `flex-grow` and the second for `flex-shrink`? (sorry i know i can just look this up but i'll ask it anyway though.). I really appreciate your help. It won't go to waste as i will also do my part in learning it to the most basic part

Comment: I'll make it easy: right click any element you want in any page (using Chrome) and select "Inspect element". Provided the devtools window has enough width, on the right hand side you'll see a few tabs: Styles, Computed, .... Go to Styles and in `element.style {}` (on top), write `flex: 1` and press Tab. Now click on the small arrow between `flex` and `1`. That's the order. You can do this for any shorthand CSS attribute.

Comment: wow. didn't know that. thanks a lot for the info. i know it is pretty dumb but i really do appreciate the help. more power to you!